# In the phrase 'Answer True or False:' should 'True' and 'False' be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, writing-style

> Answer True or False:
>   Answer true or false:
>   Answer Yes or No:
>   Answer yes or no:

Should I capitalize these words or not? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the questions that follow include checkboxes or what-have-you that are labeled "True" and "False" then use "True" and "False" above.  Otherwise (no boxes or they're labeled in lower case) use lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is primarily a style question. The wording "Answer True or False" often appears as a short form of the instruction

> Answer [each of the following questions by identifying the statement as] true or false:

or of the instruction

> Answer [each of the following questions by appending the word] True or False [to the statement]:

In the first instance, the instruction is to indicate whether each statement is true or false, which the answerer can do in such varied ways, as with "The statement is true," "It's true," "True," or "T." In the second instance, the instruction is to attach the word "True" or "False" to each statement, as appropriate.

I would imagine that in most testing or Q&A situations, the latter instruction is the one that the test creator intends. That being the case, the wording "Answer True or False:" seems preferable to me. You also have the option of italicizing the words *True* and *False*, whether they are initial-capped or lowercase, to signal that you are using them as the name of a word (or in this case, as the name of an acceptable answer):

> "Answer *True* or *False*:"

or

> "Answer *true* or *false*:"

The handling of "Answer Yes or No:" follows the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It should be yes or no and true or false. The only exception for the upper case would be proper nouns, proper acroymns, dates, and of course sentence starters. This being said, I can see why you would think Yes or No. I would recommend that if you are building a website or writing a poll.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's up to a matter of preference and style more than anything. I tend to capitalise "true" and "false" to remain consistent with the answer choices (which are usually capitalised).